# Decoding Arabic base64 file attachment in InfoPath

Tags: c#, encoding, arabic, infopath

I'm using the decode code in this Microsoft article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/892730

The code works fine if the content of the document is English. However, when the content is Arabic it doesn't work.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: How do you know it "doesn't work"? What are the symptoms? What's the file format of your attachment? How do you know it is the code, and not the way you view the attachment, that is the problem? Can you give a sample of input and output?

Comment: Is your file in unicode format or not?

Comment: I debug the code and the result string is not the text that was originally in the file. It is just strange data. The original file is in Unicode format.

Comment: The linked code attempts to read your original file as UTF-16 (`Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(fileName)`). If the original file is in a different encoding then this will cause issues.

Comment: Unfortunately the PC i use doesn't have access to internet, I'm submitting this from mobile phone. So I can't provide you with the output. But it is strange text like black diamonds. Like this: ����� ���

Comment: Why won't you just use a `StreamReader` with unicode encoding to read your file and work with the data?

Comment: Thank you all. Apparently it is the encoding of the original attachment. It was ASCII. It was a silly problem. Thanks